# QML: Cannot detect PressAndHold event

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am testing on my desktop and can't seem to get qml to recognize the PressAndHold event.

```
 Button
{
    id: btn_draw

    style: cgButtonStyle

    width: isPortrait() ? Game.getBannerHeight() : Game.getBannerHeight() / 3
    height: isPortrait() ? Game.getBannerHeight() : Game.getBannerHeight() / 3

    MouseArea
    {
        onPressAndHold: iPod4.play()
    }

    // Much more code
```

Am I missing a signal somewhere or something?  Do I need to add anything else in order for QML to recognize the PressAndHold event?  Is it possible other code is preventing PressAndHold from working?

Comment: For the record, if I add onDoubleClicked...that doesn't work either.

Comment: Nvm, solved it boys.  I was missing anchor.fill and mouse area was microscopic...I guess.  Hence, it seemed like the PressAndHold event wasn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `MouseArea` anchors... the mouse area is zero-sized, and so you can't click it...

Simply modify like that:

```
MouseArea
{
    anchors.fill: parent
    onPressAndHold: iPod4.play()
}
```

and it would work.

Comment: Ok, I see only now that you've already answered in comments... sorry